# hide button in workflow openerp

Tags: odoo

I have workflow with 4 states : new ,negotiation,won,lost and a button . I want my button only  visible in state won and invisible in other state .

Here my code

```
<button string="Nhập kho" name="themkho" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in',['new','negotiation','lost'])]}"/>
```

[Image](http://upanh.biz/images/2014/11/22/12345.jpg)

Sorry , i don't have enough reputation to post image

1 - how can i hide my button when i create  ?

2- how can i use my button only 1 time and afterthat it will invisible for all state ?

3- how can hide edit button in state negotiation,won and lost ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you not add states attribute in button like this:

```
<button string="Nhập kho" name="themkho" type="object" **states="won"**/>
```

Regards,